# Remove records from a shapefile

Tags: gis, shapefile

I have a complete shapefile, but I just need 30% of the .dbf records. I clean the .dbf easily in SQL, but the connection with the shapefile is lost.

So, how can clean the entire shapefile of the records I don't need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution.

1) Make a query removing the un-needed elements: RightClick (RC) on Layer>Properties>Defintion Query> Query Builder > ... > ok

2) RC on Layer > Open Attribute Table > table Options Button > Select All Records > Close the Table

3) RC on Layer > Data > Export Data > Select target folder > Save as type "Shape file" in the scroll-down menu

4) Will ask if you want the new shape file added as layer in current project Y/N

5) Done!

More details [here](http://barbareeduke.com/downloads/HOWTO%20Export%20data%20ArcMap9.pdf):